# How to redirect stdout to both file and console?

Tags: julia

Don't have no idea how to do it. How can I collect info to a txt file and print to terminal? I need it to output to txt file and to terminal
[image: Don't have no idea how to do it]

Comment: Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code. Paste the code.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is the tee shell function.  You could emulate it with a function based on julia's print function method that allows you to specify the IO destination:

```
function teeprint(io1::IO, io2::IO, xs...)
    print(io1, xs...)
    print(io2, xs...)
end
```

Used this way:

```
fp = open("temptext.txt", "w")

lines = split("""
print([io::IO], xs...)

  Write to io (or to the default output stream stdout if io is not given) 
  a canonical (un-decorated) text
  representation. The representation used by print includes minimal 
  formatting and tries to avoid Julia-specific
  details.
""", "\n")

for line in lines
    teeprint(fp, stdout, line)
    teeprint(fp, stdout, "\n")
end

close(fp)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you need an IO object like I did, you can make a struct with some behavior:

```
struct TeeIO <: IO
    io::IO
end

Base.write(t::TeeIO, x::UInt8) = (write(t.io, x); write(stdout, x))
Base.write(t::TeeIO, x::AbstractString) = (write(t.io, x); write(stdout, x))
Base.write(t::TeeIO, x::Union{SubString{String}, String}) = (write(t.io, x); write(stdout, x))

...
f = open(...) # Get your file
output_io = TeeIO(f)
```