# Redirect stio and still printing in the terminal

Tags: redirect, terminal, julia, output, stdio

Thanks to [this great answer from @Przemyslaw Szufel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69059106/10094437), we can easily redirect stdio output into a file providing its path.

I wanted to know if it is possible to both redirect stio output to a file and still continue print it in the terminal. That is probably an easy feature to achieve but I could not find it!
And obviously not running the code twice :)

Comment: This might help: https://gist.github.com/mkitti/e4f7d2a0ed00f1b7ca9d37838f7011dd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a Tee Stream such as https://github.com/fredrikekre/TeeStreams.jl/.
Unfortunately the interface of `redirect_stdio` does not accept abstract `IO` for its sink. It requires it to be an `IOStream` which is a concrete Julia type.
So it seems like there is no good way with the `redirect_stdio` via streams.

However `redirect_stdio` does accept sockets and named pipes and this is a way you could consider (yet too complex for this simple tasks - maybe someone finds a more elegant solution).

First you need to create a pipe server that will be running asynchronously in your REPL session (this is code for Windows for Linux you will probably need to remove `\\.\pipe\` from the pipe name):

```
using Sockets 
srv = Sockets.listen(raw"\\.\pipe\TeePipe")
mystdout = stdout
@async begin
    open("log.txt", "w") do f
       sock = accept(srv)
       while !eof(sock)
           line = readline(sock)
           println(mystdout, line)
           flush(mystdout)
           println(f, line)
           flush(f)
       end
    end    
end
```

Now at the same REPL session you create the client:

```
teelogger = Sockets.connect(raw"\\.\pipe\TeePipe")
```

And here is a sample REPL session showing that this works:

```
julia> redirect_stdio(stdout=teelogger) do
              println("Line1")
              println("Line2")
              @show 3+4
       end
Line1
Line2
3 + 4 = 7
7

shell> more log.txt
Line1
Line2
3 + 4 = 7
```

Comment: I hoped this could be done with Julia's base and without a package!

Comment: Julia has not quite complete API here. I remember that other languages eg. Java used to have inbuilt APIs for splitting /multiplying streams. And `redirect_stdio` does not accept the `IO` abstract type :(

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69131365/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-both-file-and-console/69141668#69141668.

Comment: Bill, if @JKHA can control the command that prints I would go with `TeeLogger` from https://github.com/JuliaLogging/LoggingExtras.jl

Comment: TeeLogger is versatile -- I was showing a way to do the tee output with base Julia.